# Inductively prove that this sequence of integrals is bounded.

Tags: integration, inequality, induction, integral-inequality

EDIT: I have an attempted solution to this in a post below, it is very long, but still incomplete.

EDIT:Alright, I've pretty much almost finished my solution, but my biggest problem is the 2nd integral, rightmost inequality. I cannot find a way to evaluate it and compare it to the n=1 case for the upper integral, which should give me what I need.

EDIT: still stuck!

EDIT: 10 days later, I still need help with this..

Can someone please help me with this? I'm not even sure where to go from here.

Here is the problem:

---

Prove that

$$\frac{1}{2}<\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^{2n}}}\le0.52359,$$

for any integer $n\ge1$,

And that

$$\frac{1}{2}<\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{4-x+x^{3}}}\le0.52359$$

---

Now I can do this for the $n=1$ case, as obviously this simply integrates to $\arcsin{\frac{1}{2}}$ giving $\frac{\pi}{6}$, but I'm completely stumped on any doing any further for this question.

All help very appreciated, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the interest of completeness, and at the risk of duplication, I will include my solution of the first part of the question.
$$
\frac12\lt\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-x^{2n}}}
$$
since $1\lt\dfrac1{\sqrt{1-x^{2n}}}$ on $\left(0,\frac12\right)$.

Furthermore, since $\dfrac1{\sqrt{1-x^{2n}}}\le\dfrac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ on $\left(0,\frac12\right)$ for $n\ge1$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-x^{2n}}}
&\le\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\\
&=\arcsin\left(\tfrac12\right)-\arcsin(0)\\
&=\frac\pi6\\[6pt]
&\doteq0.5235987755983
\end{align}
$$

---

**Second Part**

$$
\frac12<\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{4-x+x^3}}
$$
since $\frac12\lt\dfrac1{\sqrt{4-x+x^3}}$ on $(0,1)$.

Furthermore, $4-x+x^3$ is convex on $[0,1]$. Looking at its tangents at $0$ and $1$, and its minimum on $[0,1]$,

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

we get
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{4-x+x^3}}\le\min\left(\frac1{\sqrt{4-x}},\frac1{\sqrt{4-2/\sqrt{27}}},\frac1{\sqrt{2+2x}}\right)
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{4-x+x^3}}\\
&\le\int_0^{2/\sqrt{27}}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{4-x}}
+\int_{2/\sqrt{27}}^{1-1/\sqrt{27}}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{4-2/\sqrt{27}}}
+\int_{1-1/\sqrt{27}}^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{2+2x}}\\
&=2\left(2-\sqrt{4-2/\sqrt{27}}\right)
+\frac{1-3/\sqrt{27}}{\sqrt{4-2/\sqrt{27}}}
+\left(2-\sqrt{4-2/\sqrt{27}}\right)\\
&=6-\frac{11-3/\sqrt{27}}{\sqrt{4-2/\sqrt{27}}}\\[6pt]
&\doteq0.5182655150624\\[18pt]
&\lt0.5235987755983
\end{align}
$$

---

**On Strict Inequality**

Suppose we know that $f(x)\le g(x)$ on $[a,b]$ and that $f(x)\lt g(x)$ on $(a,b)$. If $f$ and $g$ are continuous and $a\lt b$, then we can pick any $a'$ and $b'$ so that $a\lt a'\lt b'\lt b$. $g-f$ is continuous on the compact set $[a',b']$ so it attains its minimum on $[a',b']$ that is
$$
g(x)-f(x)\ge m\gt0\text{ for }x\in[a',b']\subset(a,b)
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_a^b(g(x)-f(x))\,\mathrm{d}x
&\ge\int_{a'}^{b'}(g(x)-f(x))\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&\ge\int_{a'}^{b'}m\,\mathrm{d}x\\[6pt]
&=m(b'-a')\\[12pt]
&\gt0
\end{align}
$$
so that we have the strict inequality
$$
\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\lt\int_a^bg(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$

Comment: How did you choose your integral limits for the 3 functions?

Comment: @user65132: They are the points where the functions intersect $4-x=4-2/\sqrt{27}$ at $x=2/\sqrt{27}$ and $2+2x=4-2/\sqrt{27}$ at $x=1-1/\sqrt{27}$.

Comment: Ah, I see. And what about the choice of functions? Are they distinct, or did you just choose any functions satisfying the inequality?

Comment: @user65132: as I mentioned, these are the tangents of $4-x+x^3$ at $x=0$ and $x=1$ and the minimum of $4-x+x^3$ on $[0,1]$. I've added a graphic to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help!

Answer (score 4):

First note that the leftmost inequality is trivial, since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2n}}}\geq 1$.

Now note that for $x<1$, $x^{2(n+1)} = x^2x^{2n} \leq x^{2n}$. Hence $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2(n+1)}}}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2n}}}$ for all $x<1$. Thus $\displaystyle\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-x^{2(n+1)}}} \leq \displaystyle\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-x^{2n}}}$. The rightmost inequality now follows by induction.

Comment: Hello,

Thanks so much for getting back to me so quickly. I get almost all of this, except your deduction for the left inequality.

I just can't fully see yet how the inequality you've given guarantees the integral to be greater than a half.

Comment: any help buddy?

Comment: He's using $\int_a^b f(x)\ge (b-a)c$ where $f\ge c$ in this range.

Comment: Well. If $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2n}}}\geq 1$, then $\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2n}}}\,\mathrm{d}x\geq\int_0^\frac{1}{2} 1\,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: That's so obvious now, thanks a lot!

Comment: Would I be correct to then go on to have to prove that the first integral given is greater than the second integral below, therefore satisfying the same inequality?

Comment: Actually, I think the leftmost inequality for the second integral is incorrect. If $x\in\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$, then $4-x+x^3\geq 4-x\geq \frac{7}{2}$. Hence $\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x+x^3}}\leq \sqrt{\frac{2}{7}} < 1$, whence the integral is actually less than $\frac{1}{2}$. I suspect the definition of this integral might be off by a factor $2$, since $2\sqrt{\frac{2}{7}}$ is slightly greater than $1$.

Comment: That aside though, I think your idea to compare the integral(s) above to the one below is the right way to proceed.

Comment: That is because I made a stupid mistake. The integral goes from 0 to 1, as I have now edited to show.

Thanks for pointing that out to me!

Comment: @Abel see below

Answer (score 1):

Alright, here is my attempt at a full solution, can anyone tell me if it is correct?

EDIT: Somewhere along the way I realise I have went wrong, which is pointed out in this post.

---

For the first integral:

Trivially:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2n}}}\ge1,    \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$

From here, we use

$$\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^{2n}}}\ge\int_0^\frac{1}{2}dx=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$\implies \frac{1}{2}\le\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^{2n}}} \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$

[Note, I have proven the $\le$ relationship here, but I don't know how to also confirm the $<$ relationship between the integral and $\frac{1}{2}$, any help here?]

Now, for $x \in[0,\frac{1}{2}],x^{2(n+1)}\le x^{2n}$

$$\implies \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2(n+1)}}}\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2n}}}\forall n\in\mathbb{N},x\in[0,\frac{1}{2}]$$

$$\implies\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^{2(n+1)}}}\le\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^{2n}}}\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$

With this information, we can now prove the statement:

$$\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^{2n}}}\le0.52359,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$

For $n=1$,

$$\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^{2(1)}}}=\left[\arcsin{x}\right]_0^\frac{1}{2}=\frac{\pi}{6}\approx0.52359$$

Assume statement true for $n=k$

$$\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^{2k}}}\le0.52359$$

Now, for $n=k+1$, we know:

$$\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^{2(k+1)}}}\le\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^{2k}}}\le0.52359$$

Therefore

$$\frac{1}{2}\le\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^{2n}}}\le0.52359,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$

Again, I still can't prove the strict inequality on the left, unless I already have and just cannot see it.

---

Now for the second integral:

For $x\in[0,1]$,$$4\ge 4-x+x^3\ge3$$

As $x\ge x^3$

So we know that $$\sqrt{4}=2\ge\sqrt{4-x+x^3}$$

$$\implies \frac{1}{2}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x+x^3}}$$

$$\implies\frac{1}{2}=\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}dx\le\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{4-x+x^3}}$$

Again, I cannot prove strict inequality here, and would greatly appreciate help for that.

Now for the rightmost inequality.

Statement:

$$\frac{1}{2}\left[\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right]=\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

The proof for this is very trivial. The first integral equates to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, the second to $\frac{\pi}{6}$

Moving on, we know that $$\forall x\in[0,1], \sqrt{4-x+x^3}>\sqrt{1-x^2}, always.$$

$$\implies \frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x+x^3}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

In typing this, I have just realised I made a huge mistake, and the rest of my solution to this is now invalid.

I was going to go on to say that $$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{4-x+x^3}}\le\frac{1}{2}\left[\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x+x^3}}-\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x+x^3}}\right]\le\frac{1}{2}\left[\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right]=\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

But this is clearly incorrect. Any ideas, anyone?

Right now I'm trying to toy with the relationship$$\frac{1}{3}\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Comment: @Abel pick me apart please!

Comment: What you could do instead is substitute $u = \frac{1}{2}x$ to obtain the new integral $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{4-x+x^3}} = \int_0^\frac{1}{2} \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{2}u+2u^3}}$.

Comment: @Abel Thanks a lot, that's a great idea. But how do I compare the integrals?

I tried showing that $1-\frac{1}{2}u+2u^{3}\ge 1-x^{2}, \forall x,u \in[0,\frac{1}{2}]$, but this isn't actually true, (case $u,x=0.25$) and I can't think of another way to do this. 

Thanks for all the help so far, by the way.

Comment: Also, I still haven't figured out how to prove the strict inequality on the left sides of the integrals.

Comment: anyone at all? I'd bounty this, but I can't find the damn button.

Comment: For the strict inequality you could argue something like this:

For $x\in\left[0,\frac{1}{4}\right]$ we have $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2n}}}\geq 1$ and for $x\in\left[\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}\right]$ we have $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2n}}}\geq\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{4^{2n}}}}$. Hence $\displaystyle\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-x^{2n}}} \geq \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{4^{2n}}}} > \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: And for the integral inequality? That's the one that has me stuck the most...

Comment: For the integral inequality my suggested substitution doesn't seem to be as useful as I originally thought. I now think the way to go is to write $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{4-x+x^3}} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{4}(x-x^3)}}+\int_\frac{1}{2}^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{4}(x-x^3)}}\right)$.
Now see if you can show that both these integrals are bounded by $\displaystyle\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-x^{2n}}}$ for some $n$.

Comment: This new function gives me the same problems as the last one. They overlap in that interval, so I cannot make any conclusions based on that.

Comment: I'm startng to think that an elegant, non calculator solution to this does not exist.